# How to convert python3 post request with both files and params to curl

Tags: python-3.x, bash, curl

I have `python3` script which correctly uploaded image to site and I want to do exactly the same via `curl` command.

```py
import requests


url = 'http://1.2.3.4/upload'
files = {'image': open('foo.jpg', 'rb')}
params = {'bar': 'baz'}
requests.post(url, files=files, params=params)
```

```sh
# incorrect
curl -XPOST -F 'image=foo.jpg' -d 'bar=baz' 'http://1.2.3.4/upload'
```

I expect command like this will upload `foo.jpg` with param `baz`, but it seems to `-F` is ignored by `curl` when `-d` is specified.

I want `curl` with file name specified, rather than whole file data inside command like `curlify` library does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't use `-F` and `-d` together, former overrides the latter,
2. You need to prefix filename with an `@` sign,
3. `-F` implies `-X POST`, and when it is used all data is sent as form-data, so `bar=baz` will not be appended to URL as with `-G` and `-d`, you need to append it manually.

```
curl -F 'image=@foo.jpg' 'http://1.2.3.4/upload?bar=baz'
```

Comment: Thank you, `@` helps to specify image, but argument `baz` is still ignored.
When I execute my python script server logs:
`"POST /upload?bar=baz HTTP/1.1"`
When I execute your `curl` server logs:
`"POST /upload HTTP/1.1"`